# How to get the old Wordpress Draft Editor view back with the Word count?

Tags: posts, wp-admin, draft

[image]
[I would like to change my drafts page back to normal. By normal I mean with the page count and other normal features shown in the 2nd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBFDl.png)

As you can see I can see the word count also in the old version. But the new one only have the capability to edit each paragraph alone.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install '[classic editor](https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/)' plugin. WordPress has updated their default editor as of version 5.